# Replace only occuring in first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Can someone help on why this is only replacing the '[m]' in the first LI?  The rest of them stay as '[m]'

```
  aData[2] = "<li>1[m]</li><li>2[m]</li><li>3[m]</li>"

  $.html( aData[2].replace('[m]','[media]') )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a *regular expression* and make it *global*:

```
$.html( aData[2].replace(/\[m\]/g,'[media]') )
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to use a regular expression to replace all in javascript, in this case it would be

```
$.html( aData[2].replace(/\[m\]/g,'[media]') )
```

Comment: Yeah, yours will not work :). You need to remove quotes on the regular expression to make it regular expression object, not string. Check in jsfiddle I provided.

Answer (score 1):

Javascripts `replace` method only replaces the first matched item unless you use a regular expression:

http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-replace

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression literal, `/[m]/`, instead of letting the string `'[m]'` get implicitly converted to a regular expression. That way you can add the `/g` ("replace all") flag:

```
  $.html( aData[2].replace(/[m]/g,'[media]') )
```

though I should add that you actually want `\[m\]` rather than `[m]`, so that you match the literal square-brackets:

```
  $.html( aData[2].replace(/\[m\]/g,'[media]') )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it a global replace.

```
var mre = new RegExp( "[m]", "g" );

aData[2] = "<li>1[m]</li><li>2[m]</li><li>3[m]</li>";
$.html( aData[2].replace(mre,'[media]') );
```